# please help me tune the below SQL Server query..its running forever

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, performance, query-performance

```
Declare 
 @bst varchar(1000),
 @pst varchar(1000), 
 @ost varchar(1000),

 @t_cnt int = 1;

WHILE @t_cnt <= (SELECT count(*) FROM t_temp)

BEGIN


 SELECT @bst = g_Search_Text FROM t_temp WHERE id = @t_cnt; 
 SELECT @pst = p_Search_Text FROM t_temp WHERE id = @t_cnt;
 SELECT @ost = o_Search_Text FROM t_temp WHERE id = @t_cnt;

       WHILE CHARINDEX('  ',@bst) > 0 
       BEGIN
              SET @bst = replace(@bst,'  ',' ')
       END                        
       WHILE CHARINDEX('  ',@pst) > 0 
       BEGIN
              SET @pst = replace(@pst,'  ',' ')
       END                        
       WHILE CHARINDEX('  ',@ost) > 0 
       BEGIN
              SET @ost = replace(@ost,'  ',' ')
       END

                update t_temp set b_Search_Text=@bst WHERE id = @t_cnt; 
               update t_temp set p_Search_Text=@pst WHERE id = @t_cnt; 
                update t_temp set o_Search_Text=@ost WHERE id = @t_cnt; 
 SET @t_cnt = @t_cnt + 1
END;
```

Comment: So what are you trying to achieve?  How do you expect people to help you if all you post is a broken query?  Sample input?  Expected output?

Comment: @Eric - note that the OP isn't saying the code doesn't do what it's supposed to; he's saying it takes forever to run.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing you need to look at is that SQL is a *set based* way of solving problems. In traditional programming languages, you'd loop through each row, apply some kind of logic, find the next row, rinse-repeat. In the database world, a set-based approach means that you tell the database what you want to do on a *set of rows*, not row-by-row.

This is the root of your performance problem.

The following code uses a [recursive common table expression](https://sqlsunday.com/2013/02/17/recursive-cte/) to repeat the `REPLACE(..., '  ', ' ')` operation until it's not needed anymore (which is kind of row-by-row in a sense), but it does that on the entire table, so I expect it to be considerably more efficient.

It then takes that result and applies it back to the table using a [cross-UPDATE](https://sqlsunday.com/2014/02/23/cross-updates/).

```
WITH cte AS (
    --- 1. This is the anchor of the recursion: here are
    ---    all the rows that need fixing:
    SELECT id,
           b_Search_Text,
           p_Search_Text,
           o_Search_Text
    FROM t_temp
    WHERE b_Search_Text LIKE '%  %'
       OR p_Search_Text LIKE '%  %'
       OR o_Search_Text LIKE '%  %'

    UNION ALL

    --- 2. Perform the REPLACE() as many times as necessary,
    ---    until there are no more double-space occurrences:
    SELECT id,
           REPLACE(b_Search_Text, '  ', ' '),
           REPLACE(p_Search_Text, '  ', ' '),
           REPLACE(o_Search_Text, '  ', ' ')
    FROM cte
    WHERE b_Search_Text LIKE '%  %'
       OR p_Search_Text LIKE '%  %'
       OR o_Search_Text LIKE '%  %')

--- 3. Join the result of the cleanup back to the "t_temp"
---    table, and apply the results using a cross-UPDATE:
UPDATE t_temp
SET t.b_Search_Text=cte.b_Search_Text,
    t.p_Search_Text=cte.p_Search_Text,
    t.o_Search_Text=cte.o_Search_Text
FROM t_temp AS t
INNER JOIN cte ON t.id=cte.id
--- ... but only those rows from the cte that have been fixed!
WHERE NOT (cte.b_Search_Text LIKE '%  %'
        OR cte.p_Search_Text LIKE '%  %'
        OR cte.o_Search_Text LIKE '%  %');
```

Because you haven't provided table definitions, I've made the assumption that `id` is a unique primary key in your table. If it isn't, this code (and yours) won't work.

You will probably get a "Types don't match" error, in the cte. If you do, you'll need to explicitly `CAST` or `CONVERT` the result of the `REPLACE()` so the datatypes of the columns in the recursion match those of the columns in the anchor (i.e. in the `t_temp` table).

Also, you could speed up this process by declaring a unique clustered index (or primary key) on the `id` column:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK ON t_temp (id);
```